# Intersecting angles on trigonometric circle

Tags: trigonometry

after solving

$|\sin(2 x - \pi/12)|\le\sqrt(2)/2$

I get two interval solutions which intersect eachother,

1. $5 \pi/12 + k \pi \le x \le \pi/6 + k \pi$
   and
2. $11\pi/12 + k \pi \le x\le 2\pi/3 + k \pi$

Since the solutions I get arent the basic, I don't have a picture in my mind how they look and intersect.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Note that $5\pi/12 > \pi/6$ and $11\pi/12 > 2\pi/3,$ so both of your intervals are empty and so is their intersection. You may have some errors in your calculations; you might get better answers if you showed _all_ of your work on the problem. (And of course format it in MathJax, otherwise people are less likely to attempt to read it.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Also note that when $\sin$ is negative, the angle is also. So that means $$-\frac{\pi}{4}\le2x-\frac{\pi}{12}\le\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Can you solve it from here?

Answer (score -1):

$$\left|\sin\left(2x-\dfrac\pi{12}\right)\right|\le\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$$

$$\iff2\sin^2\left(2x-\dfrac\pi{12}\right)\le1$$

Using $2\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$

$$\iff\cos\left(4x-\dfrac\pi6\right)\ge0$$

$$\implies2m\pi-\dfrac\pi2\le4x-\dfrac\pi6\le2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here?